# Dynamically resizing an iframe that uses AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

I am attempting to **dynamically resize an iframe**. This wasn't too hard, until I changed the iframe page to use **AJAX with jQuery**. I am attaching a function to the iframe body's resize event that should resize the iframe as well. It seems that after it started using AJAX it would no longer trigger the resize event.

Here is the code I have in the **parent site**:

```
$(function(){
    var iframe = $('#myiframe');

    iframe.load( function() {
        var iframe_content = iframe.contents().find('#content');

        iframe_content.resize( function() {
            var elem = $(this);
            var newHeight = elem.height();

          // Resize the iframe.
          iframe.css({ height: newHeight });
      });

        // Resize the iframe immediately
        iframe_content.resize();
    });
});
```

Here is the AJAX form in the **iframe site**:

```
<form onsubmit="jQuery.ajax({type: 'GET',
                             data: $(this).serialize(), 
                             url:  '/employeedirectory/employee/ajaxUpdate',
                             success:function( data, textStatus ) {
                                    $('#results').html(data);

                                    // Go to the parent document, find the content div, and call its resize event
                                    $(document, parent.window.document).contents().find('#myiframe').contents().find('#content').resize();
                                },
                            error: function( XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {} }); 
                return false;"
        id="searchForm">
</form>
```

If I run `$('#myiframe').contents().find('#content').resize()` on the parent site to force the resize event then it works just fine. But it doesn't appear that it is calling that `onsuccess` like I want. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What's with all `$(document, parent.window.document).contents().find('#myiframe').contents().find('#content').resize();`? Why not just do `$("#content")` since you're already in the iframe?

Comment: I had tried to do `$("#content").resize()` from within the form, but it wasn't working, so I was trying to call `resize()` by starting at the parent document.

Comment: Also, in your first snippet, you're dealing with the body, not the content div. why are you triggering resize on the content div rather than the body where the event is defined? sorry for all the questions, i'm trying to understand your code. At this point it's unclear where the real problem is. is the ajax failing? why isn't the resize event being triggered? is your selector not selecting any elements?

Comment: No problem. I think you're right, I could just attach the resize event handler to the content div's resize event, not the body. I believe it should work either way, though, right? When the content div is resizing then the body should be resizing, too. I will update the code accordingly.

Comment: you have to remember, you're dealing with two different instances of jquery, there may be some unexpected results when it comes to events that were bound using a different instance of jquery than the one that's triggering the event.

Comment: Since calling `$('#directory').contents().find('#content').resize()` from the parent site resizes everything just fine, is there any way I can use the iframe site to call that code in the parent site?